# TFS Builds Queuing

Tags: tfs, build-process, build-automation

I'm facing this issue in a build.

```
Other Errors and Warnings
 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Failed to create directory '\\win-akk2jup2ka\share\UICoded Build\UICoded Build_20110817.4'.  
 Details: The network path was not found.
```

Comment: Is the server share reachable?

Comment: Switch the msbuild out put to Diagnostic (/verbosity:diagnostic) and then check the log, it should tell where the access was.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your UNC path is missing a leading backslash. The message you provided references the following path:

```
\win-akk2jup2ka\share\UICoded Build\UICoded Build_20110817.4
```

Which should be:

```
\\win-akk2jup2ka\share\UICoded Build\UICoded Build_20110817.4
```

Check your drop folder in the build definition editor and make sure that it starts with two backslashes. If that's not the problem, verify that the build service account has "modify" permissions for that folder in both NTFS and on the share. For more information, see the [Set up Drop Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394.aspx) topic on MSDN.

Comment: HI .... JIM i have mentioned correct path can you plz provide a complete walkthrough how to permissions for share or dropdown location .....    ...........  share is a account of administrator type

Comment: @Divya, I've added a link to the help topic on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the build definition and provide this path for drop location

```
\\win-akk2jup2ka\share\UICoded Build\
```